# Split and shift RGB channels in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, rgb

What I'm trying to do is recreating what is commonly called an "RGB shift" effect, which is very easy to achieve with image manipulation programs.

I imagine I can "split" the channels of the image by either opening the image as a matrix of triples or opening the image three times and every time operate just on one channel, but I wouldn't know how to "offset" the channels when merging them back together (possibly by creating a new image and position each channel's [0,0] pixel in an offsetted position?) and reduce each channel's opacity as to not show just the last channel inserted into the image.

Has anyone tried to do this? Do you know if it is possible? If so, how did you do it?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: From the rules: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: However the answer of your questions are: *Yes*,*Yes*,*No*

Comment: Now it should be better :)

Comment: Yeah, let me re-answer: *Yes*, *Yes*, *By doing the minimal effort and Googleing on how to change the index of a matrix*

Comment: This is easy to do with Pillow, using the Image `.split` and `.merge` methods. The only (slightly) fiddly part is offsetting the bands: you need to create new single band images of the appropriate size to do that.

Comment: @LucaGiorgi: I don't see in what way the question is off-topic. You may complain about lack of effort, but not subjectivity. And the OP explains what he knows and what he is missing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just don't agree. Id close "how to add 1+1 in python" question because it lacks effort and I don't want to encourage people to ask that type of questions. Just different oppinions I guess

Comment: @AnderBiguri: the OP was clearly on the wrong track with the opacity issue, probably because of a misundertanding of the image structure. Less obvious than you think.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I just dont agree. Calling your answer not obvious is definitely not right. Its almost a one liner in python. Anyway, don't want to  discuss more, I am just very hars to people that show no effort on showing what they tried. Original question had "please give me a tutorial".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per color plane, replace the pixel at `(X, Y)` by the pixel at `(X-1, Y+3)`, for example. (Of course your shifts will be different.)

You can do that in-place, taking care to loop by increasing or decreasing coordinate to avoid overwriting.

There is no need to worry about transparency.